Alpine Expression Error: error is not defined
Project with TALL (Tailwind, Alpine, Laravel, Livewire) Stack and Filament
I got in local/dev mode the follwing warning (in prod it does not happens, so it maybe has todo with some dev-packages?):
Alpine Expression Error: error is not defined

Expression: "error"

 <div x-show=​"error" x-text=​"error" class=​"text-sm text-danger-600 dark:​text-danger-400" style=​"display:​ none;​">​</div>​ 

And the associated error in my console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at [Alpine] error (eval at safeAsyncFunction (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:1176:21), <anonymous>:3:32)
    at livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:1198:23
    at tryCatch (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:1118:14)
    at livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:3609:19
    at reactiveEffect (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:2417:18)
    at Object.effect2 [as effect] (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:2392:7)
    at effect (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:763:35)
    at wrappedEffect (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:779:29)
    at Function.<anonymous> (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:3609:5)
    at flushHandlers (livewire.js?id=cc800bf4:1283:48)

I search google, the filament discord channel etc. but havent found anything similar. I dont know where this error exactly come from and how to fix it. Anyone some tipps?

It means you have a  conditionally shown when the "error" variable has a true value, but that variable doesn't exist or is out of scope

Yes, but those error divs are automatically generated by filament. So i dont know how to fix that

Try to see if this discussion in the filament repo can help you
